# How to get URL of Vaadin resources path?

Tags: java, eclipse, vaadin, vaadin7

I use Eclipse + Vaadin framework.

At first I save my image into the WEB-INF folder.
Then I load this image into the FileResource variable, create Image variable and then add Image variable into Layout.

The page URL to the image resource looks like: http://servername/sitename/APP/connector/0/16/source/qwerty1.png

How to get URL in that format for use image externally?

Variable basepath returned local path: "..../WEB-INF/qwerty1.png"

```
String str = (String) VaadinService.getCurrent().getBaseDirectory().
                       getAbsolutePath() +"/WEB-INF/qwerty1.png";

File temp = new File(str);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(temp);
fos.write(os.toByteArray());
fos.flush();
fos.close();

String basepath = VaadinService.getCurrent().getBaseDirectory().
                   getAbsolutePath() +"/WEB-INF/qwerty1.png";
FileResource resource = new FileResource(new File(basepath));
Image image2 = new Image("Image from file", resource);
addComponent(image2);
```

Comment: You better use a ThemeResource and put your image in your Vaadin theme folder `yourproject/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/yourtheme`. Reference it with `new ThemeResource("qwerty1.png");`

Comment: I can it. But problem is I cant get link to this image for use externally eg use as image in other site.

Comment: Alejandro is right. The `webapp` folder is for your static resources. That's also the place where you put your HTML or JSP files. You don't need to use the subfolder VAADIN for this though.

Comment: Thanks!! Its works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you put the file in `...src/main/webapp/VAADIN/image.png`, it should be available using for example `localhost:8080/VAADIN/image.png`.